# Generics - ? use

Tags: java, generics

JDK documentation of java.util.Stream interface has the following code snippet as an example of Collector construction.

```
Collector<Widget, ?, TreeSet<Widget>> intoSet =
         Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::add,
                      (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; });
```

The Collector.of method has the return type as `static <T,R> Collector<T,R,R>`

Does the ? in the return type in the example is just a convenient way to refer to the next generic type as those two have been declared as same in the method signature. And do all the following three statement are one and the same:

```
Collector<Widget, ?, TreeSet<Widget>> intoSet =
             Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::add,
                          (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; });
Collector<Widget, TreeSet<Widget>, TreeSet<Widget>> intoSet =
             Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::add,
                          (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; });
Collector<Widget, TreeSet<Widget>, ?> intoSet =
             Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::add,
                          (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; });
```

Comment: I guess a `?` wildcard is used here because the compiler is able to infer all `Collector` type variables without the need to explicitly declare as `TreeSet`. The three statements are not strictly the same, but if the intention is to use the `Collector` to do `Stream.collect(Collector)`, then they will all work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What is a `wildcard`?

> In generic code, the question mark (`?`), called the `wildcard`,
>   represents **an unknown type**. The wildcard can be used in a variety of
>   situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable;
>   sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice
>   to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument
>   for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or
>   a supertype.

#### Why is it used with `Collector.of`?

As you have already noticed `Collector.of(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R, T> accumulator, BinaryOperator<R> combiner, Characteristics... characteristics)` returns an object of type `Collector<T, R, R>` knowing that the class `Collector` has 3 type parameters which are `T`, `A` and `R` where:

- `<T>`: The type of input elements to the reduction operation.
- `<A>`: The mutable accumulation type of the reduction operation (**often hidden as an implementation detail**)
- `<R>`: The result type of the reduction operation

So as described in the javadoc we generally use a **wildcard** for the type parameter `<A>` because it is considered as **an implementation detail** since it is only an intermediate type, what really matter are the input and output type parameters respectively `T` and `R` so for the sake of simplicity/readability `?` is preferred to what should theoretically be used which is `TreeSet<Widget>` in this case.

Comment: <?> is permitted here because this is implementation detail or is it permitted here because compiler can guess the return type.  If <A> was not the implementation detail and was exposed as return type of one the methods of Collector, would that make any difference to the compiler.

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference for the compiler, at the end due to [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) you will end up with the same byte code

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Type Erasure. That clarifies my doubt

Answer (score 1):

In Java generics, the '?' is a pure wildcard that will match any type, regardless of any other types in the signature (and there is no syntax for "the next generic type").

Remember that, due to erasure, the types specified in the signature are for compile-time checking only, not for run-time.  That means that those three statements will all execute exactly the same.  The only difference between them will be if you want generic (compile-time) type checking for the different types.

Finally, note that there is also a :

```
static <T,A,R> Collector<T,A,R> of
```

method, so there could be all different types.

Comment: static <T,A,R> Collector<T,A,R> of method accepts different number of parameters. The one that matches the arguments is static <T,R> Collector<T,R,R>. If I declare intoset type as Collector<Widget, ?, ?>, it does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the ? in the return type in the example is just a convenient way
>   to refer to the next generic type as those two have been declared as
>   same in the method signature.

*No, the ? has nothing to do with next generic type. In this specific example, we know ? happens to be R. This is called type inference, and it is inferred from the statement after the '='. You could surely define a Collector where ? refers to a different type than the last generic type.*

> And do all the following three statement are one and the same:

*Yes, in terms of what intoSet really is.*
*No, in terms of how intoSet can be further used*

Don't let the grammar confuse you. This is just similar to

```
String str = "hello";
```

vs.

```
Object str = "hello";
```

In both cases, str is a string in runtime. This has nothing to do with how it is declared. But in the second case, you cannot use str as string, the compiler won't allow you because str is only declared as Object.

Same thing with generics. Java does not have declare-site variance but use-site variance. The wildcard "?" has nothing to do with how Collector.of is defined, but is all about how you want to use it.

Here `Collector<Widget, ?, TreeSet<Widget>> intoSet = ...` tells you it is a collector that collects Widget into TreeSet. But how does it collect Widget into a TreeSet? More specifically, does it directly put each Widget into the set, or it uses an intermediate accumulator, e.g. a `Stack<Widget>` , and eventually transforms the final result into TreeSet? Both of them are possible given Collector interface is defined as `Collection<T,A,R>`. However, the intoSet declaration just says "**I don't care**, it is all up to how you initialize me".

You could even define it as `Collector<?, ?, ?>`, totally fine.

As for the difference between

```
Collector<Widget, TreeSet<Widget>, TreeSet<Widget>> intoSet =
             Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::add,
                          (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; });
Collector<Widget, TreeSet<Widget>, ?> intoSet =
             Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::add,
                          (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; });
```

It once again goes to how you would like to use intoSet. For most of the time, we only care what is the input and output - for that input is the type we need to pass in, and output is the type we will eventually make use of. These two types tell a critical information about how the collector will interact with the rest of your code. Therefore you probably want to/have to specify them.

`Collector<Widget, TreeSet<Widget>, ?> intoSet` is legal but probably less useful in practice. This is because when you want to use intoSet, you have no clue what is the type of result container (therefore you cannot use it meaningfully) **by just looking at the declaration**.

Similar example:

```
 Map<?, ?> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 map.put("a", 1); //compiler complains here when you try to use map, as map is declared as <?,?>, not <String, Integer>
```